# Parse - Asynchronous Block Call

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have the following code that checks if username is taken or not in `Parse` database. The only problem is that the code is executing and execution continues to next code and then returns the result of this block.

This is leading to a problem with a check I have afterwards on true/false value.

How can I execute the same code below and wait for it to get a result. and based on that, proceed?

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"User")
query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo:username)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print("test username: " + username);
    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        usernameTaken = true;
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        usernameTaken = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a generic synchronous vs. asynchronous question and has been answered dozens of times for iOS using Objective-C.  Same problem;   you need to either cause the execution flow to wait using a semaphore or you need to provide a completion handler.

Answer (score 1):

You know, the PFQuery class, and the whole Parse library, has a detailed documentation. It should have taken you no more than 5 seconds to find that next to the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, there's a `findObjects:` method that will return the data directly:

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjects

It is however generally a very bad idea to use synchronous requests, especially from the main thread, as this will cause your UI to freeze while the request is made (which is usually quick, but can take a lot longer if the network connection is slow or unreliable). You would be a lot better of extending the completion block paradigm to your own code to propagate the request.

Comment: But this is a request to check if username is taken or not. Basically it can't be overlooked. It would be really helpful if you can outline alternative option to addressing this verification

Answer (score 1):

First of all check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94 to better understand how it's works

You can use some `completion` block in function that include your code like this:

```
func result(completion block: (result: Bool) -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"User")
    query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo:username)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print("test username: " + username);
            if error == nil {
                // retun true with completion block
                block(result: true)
            } else {
                // return false with completion block
                block(result: false)
            }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
...
result(completion: {(result: Bool) in 
    // Here code that use result from your query
    ...
})
...
```

Or you can call some your function from `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` that will use result from query:

```
func someFunc(result: Bool) {
    // Here code that use result from your query
    ...
}
...
let query = PFQuery(className:"User")
query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo:username)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("test username: " + username);
        if error == nil {
            self.someFunc(true)
        } else {
            self.someFunc(false)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I fixed the execution but placing the check of the boolean variable usernameTaken in the if condition. Things worked after that.